# Printing List within list in python line by line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I Have created a list using the following code

```
grid = [['a' for i in range (0,5)]  for j in range (0,3)]
print grid
```

The output of the code is

```
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a','a', 'a']]
```

I want to display this list in the form

```
 [['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 
  ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
  ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']]
```

What changes should i make to get this output

I am using python 2.7

I Dont want to import any extra modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid importing any modules, as you suggested in comments, print it this way, joining the string representation of inner lists with new lines manually:

```
print '[' + ',\n '.join(str(x) for x in grid) + ']'
```

Works this way:

```
>>> grid = [['a' for i in range (0,5)]  for j in range (0,3)]
>>> print '[' + ',\n '.join(str(x) for x in grid) + ']'
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']]
```

Comment: Urgh. What if a string inside a list contains `],`? The output will be messed up

Comment: Yeah, right. Let's try again... Ok, this should be better.

Comment: @RoY: If you think an answer is helpful, remember accept it.

Comment: @Szymon  Is there any means or methond where i can store the printed output in that form in a variable and just by giving a normal print command would show the output in that form

Comment: @RoY just store it in a variable: `x = '[' + ',\n '.join(str(x) for x in grid) + ']'`

Answer (score 6):

You could simply use [`pprint.pprint()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) to do it:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> grid = [['a' for i in range (0,5)]  for j in range (0,3)]
>>> pprint(grid)
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']]
>>>
```

From the document:

> Prints the formatted representation of object on stream, followed by a newline. If stream is `None`, `sys.stdout` is used. This may be used in the interactive interpreter instead of a `print` statement for inspecting values. indent, width and depth will be passed to the `PrettyPrinter` constructor as formatting parameters.

Comment: Thank u @kevin but can i do it without importing  any extra modules such as pprint

Comment: @RoY: Well, `pprint` is a built-in module. That means every Python 2.7 has it. So actually you don't need install it. Why don't want to simply use it?

Comment: but i want to avoid it sir

Comment: @RoY: Hmm...take a look at Szymon's edited answer. But I still suggest that use `pprint`. It's the general way.

Comment: @KevinGuan +1, agree this is the way, usually.